# How do you add a Gradle Composite Build to the buildscript classpath

Tags: gradle, build, build-script

I have included a sub-project using `includeBuild` in the `settings.gradle` file. I want to reference this project in the `buildscript` `classpath`. Both `classpath project(":projectname")` and `classpath 'mygroup:subproject'` in the `build.gradle` file but this does not seem to work. I tried explicit Dependency Substitutions for the latter case in `settings.gradle` file also with

- `includeBuild('subproject') { dependencySubstitution { substitute module('mygroup:subproject') with project(':') } }`,
- `includeBuild('subproject') { dependencySubstitution { substitute module('mygroup:subproject') with project(':subproject') } }` and
- `includeBuild('subproject') { dependencySubstitution { substitute module('mygroup:subproject') with project('subproject') } }`.

which did not work.

The projects are not published as they are new and coding is WIP hence cannot be built as yet.

Comment: For the record, buildscript syntax is `classpath 'mygroup:subproject'` (don't wrap in in `project()`) so not sure why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
includeBuild('subproject') {
    dependencySubstitution { 
        substitute module("mygroup:subproject") using(project(':'))
    } 
}
```